# Распознание текста по фотографии

Tags: python-3.x

Добрый день! Хочу добавить в своё приложение возможность распознания математического текста (формулы, уравнения, выражения и т.д.). Вся разработка идёт на python 3.5. Есть ли библиотеки/сервисы/модули и т. д., которые могли бы "прочитать" весь текст с картинки?

Comment: Может это вам поможет: https://habrahabr.ru/post/149091/

Comment: Я читал этот пост, проблема в том, что у меня немного другой случай. Писать с 0 будет глупо + тут используются старые модули

Comment: @vladF с формулами конечно все намного сложнее, но pil из статьи нельзя назвать "старым модулем", он вполне себе актуален.

Comment: Окей, теперь не спорю. Думал, его нет под 3.*. Но проблема в том, что придётся в таком случае придумать алгоритмы для обработки фото(исправление перспективы, например). Всё еще надеюсь на какой-нибудь готовый вариант. Слышал про API от abbyy, но там есть или пробный период или платная подписка

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что [вопросы о том, где найти программы, библиотеки, учебники по программированию и администрированию — не стоит задавать](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)